# Libgdx not loading images on mac

Tags: java, libgdx

I am attempting to setup a Libgdx project on a Mac but I can't load any textures. Even when I use the setup app I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" 
com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load file
```

Comment: It most likely has to do with the path. Check where you load the image and what path it has. I'm 90% sure it's the path.

Comment: @Nick Im creating a desktop project in Eclipse, how would I check in that environment?

Answer (score 0):

1. check your resource pad, Your assets path may be wrong.
2. set asset path in your 'run/debug configurations/working directory'

I hope your problem has been resolved

Comment: Im creating a desktop project in Eclipse, how would I check in that environment?

Comment: i don't work with eclipse but try it. Go into the Debug/Run dialog (drop down button next to the bug/"go" buttons), and in the Arguments tab, set the Working Directory by selecting "Other" and then putting in the relevant directory name. Note that the directory can use "variables" like $workspace_loc. You can even make it prompt the user using $folder_prompt.

Comment: this is another solution . If you wish that the program run with a different directory as its working directory, here is how:

Right-click on the project name in Project Explorer, choose Properties > Run/Debug Settings > Choose the launch configuration > Edit > Arguments > Working directory
Uncheck the Use default option. For a project named foobar, the default entry here is ${workspace_loc:foobar}

If the working directory you want is a subdirectory of the project directory, then append it. For example: ${workspace_loc:foobar}/bin. Else type in an absolute path as working directory.